# MVCSiteMapProvider - show title of parent node

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, mvcsitemapprovider

I would like to be able to show the title of the parent of the current node.

Sitemap:

```
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Main Site Tile" controller="Home" action="Index">
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Some site section" controller="Section" action="Index">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Some page" controller="Section" action="Page1" />
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Some other page" controller="Section" action="Page2" />
  </mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

So, on 'Page1' I can show the title (Some page) by using:

```
Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapTitle()
```

Great. But, I would also like to show the title of the parent node (Some site section) in my _Layout page, so this would appear the same if I were viewing 'Page1' or 'Page2' (or indeed any view nested within).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using the SiteMapTitle attribute and set the Target to ParentNode.

```
[MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Mvc.Filters.SiteMapTitle("SomeKey", Target = AttributeTarget.ParentNode]
public ViewResult Show(int blogId) { 
   ViewData["SomeKey"] = "This will be the title";

   var blog = _repository.Find(blogId); 
   return View(blog); 
}
```

That will set the title of the links in the Menu and SiteMapPath.

You can also access the nodes programmatically using the static SiteMaps object.

```
var theTitle = MvcSiteMapProvider.SiteMaps.Current.CurrentNode.ParentNode.Title;
```

Alternatively, you can use the `FindSiteMapNodeFromKey("theKey")` method to find any node in the SiteMap to get its title.

Comment: This is a great solution - just one question.  Is it possible to target a specific level?  This will always show the parent, but say I have 4 levels in my sitemap and I always want to show the second level of the node I am in.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: There is no built-in way (other than using .ParentNode.ParentNode up to the level you are interested in). You could potentially use a custom attribute to flag which node to show the title of and then call .ParentNode recursively until you find the node with your flag. Just be sure to add your custom attribute to MvcSiteMapProvider_AttributesToIgnore or it will be added to the querystring. https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Using-Custom-Attributes-on-a-Node